# how to know if TypeORM methods will throw or not?

Tags: exception, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on my firt nestjs project for school, it's an nestjs API which deals with users.

**In terms of error management I would like to understand how to determine if a typeorm method like `find`, `findOne`, `remove`... have a chance of throwing an exception.**

- For example `find(userId)` will not throw if no userId exist, yet it's a promise so should I still chain a `.catch()` ?
- Are there any cases in which it would throw (database server being down for example ?)

*Coming from C languages, I tend to be trained to imagine the worst case scenarios rather than the usual behavior, and I don't find anything in documentation stating clearly about throw for each method.*

Answer (score 0):

> For example find(userId) will not throw if no userId exist, yet it's a promise so should I still chain a .catch() ?

1. No need to chain a catch. You can add the whole db call in a try-catch block. Even if you don't catch the exception it's totally fine as NestJs has an in-built exception handler.

> Are there any cases in which it would throw (database server being down for example ?)

2. Yes, this will throw an exception but as mentioned NestJs contains an in-built exception handler which will catch all unhandled exceptions and returns appropriate response for you. So, no need to add catch blocks. You can read more about it here - [Exception Filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters).

Comment: Thanks. Two folloup questions: in that case, what makes a try/catch block different from a .then().catch() ?
Also, as the original question was a little more general: where could I find a reference which states exactly the behaviour of the methods ? I am maybe too used to C describing precisely how libraries' functions are expected to succeed, fail etc... that I find surprising there doesn't seem to be any very detailed reference for TypeORM.